# Delete row from table where match exists in second table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have Table A with the following values:

```
    
+------+------+
| ID1  | ID2  |
+------+------+
| 1689 | 1709 |
| 1709 | 1689 |
| 1782 | 1709 |
| 1911 | 1247 |
| 1247 | 1468 |
| 1641 | 1468 |
| 1316 | 1304 |
| 1501 | 1934 |
| 1934 | 1501 |
| 1025 | 1101 |
+------+------+
```

and another relation (Table B) with the following values:

```
+------+------+
| ID1  | ID2  |
+------+------+
| 1641 | 1468 |
| 1911 | 1247 |
+------+------+
```

I would like to delete all rows in Table A that appear in Table B (an exact match on ID1 and ID2). Seems simple in theory but I'm having no joy with the EXISTS statement or other approaches. I'm using SQLite.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

How about: (not too sure whether this works in SQLite)

```
DELETE FROM TableA
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM TableB
              WHERE TableB.ID1 = TableA.ID1
                AND TableB.ID2 = TableA.ID2)
```

Comment: I find this syntax of SQL is extremely tricky. If TableA and TableB is the same Table, then I have to use 'TableA' to refer to the table in delete clause, and I have no way to give it an alias name; in contrast, I have to give an alias name to the table in the sub query, and have no way to use the 'id1' and 'id2' without prefix table name...

Comment: Try using a CTE for the subselect

Comment: Note that if you want NULLs to match, you have to add that explicitly, as equality comparison doesn't doesn't consider NULL=NULL to be true.

Answer (score 3):

In MSSQL you can do this: (most efficient)

DELETE a
 FROM a
 JOIN b ON a.ID1 = b.ID1 
        AND a.ID2 = b.ID2

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE a FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.ID1=b.ID1 AND a.ID2=b.ID2
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want NULLs to match.  This is an unusual need, but if you need it, standard SQL select will not suffice.

```
DELETE FROM TableA
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
  FROM TableB
    WHERE 
      (TableB.ID1 IS NULL AND TableA.ID1 IS NULL OR TableB.ID1 = TableA.ID1)
    AND 
      (TableB.ID2 IS NULL AND TableA.ID2 IS NULL OR TableB.ID2 = TableA.ID2)
)
```