# Sql Exists on same table with sub query deletes all records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**QUERY**

```
Delete from Image 
where Exists
(
  SELECT x.ImageId, ParentId, occurrences 
  from Image li 
  inner join 
  (
    SELECT  
      ImageId,    
      COUNT(*) occurrences
    FROM Image 
    GROUP BY ImageId
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ) x on li.ImageId = x.ImageId
)
```

**DATA**

```
ImageId   ParentId
a         1
a         2
b         3
c         4
```

**EXPECTED REMAINING RESULT**

```
ImageId   ParentId
b         3
c         4
```

The query in the Exists function returns the first two records with same ImageId a.

When I run the whole Delete query not ONLY these two records are deleted, but the whole table data is wiped!???

I found this SO link: [Delete row from table where match exists in second table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794028/delete-row-from-table-where-match-exists-in-second-table)

where a user comments about this tricky situation, but the comment does not help me as the solution seems open to me.

How do I have to fix the delete query?

Comment: Your query currently says: `DELETE FROM Image WHERE (<at least one row exists in this unrelated query>)`

Comment: Is DATA sample table data or the expected result? We need both anyway. [mcve]

Comment: @AaronBertrand So you say I understood the semantics of the Exists wrongly? That would explain it!

Comment: It looks like your intention is to delete images that are duplicated, but your expected results are the opposite?

Comment: EXISTS is typically used with a _correlated_ subquery, i.e. one which has a condition referencing its outer table.

Comment: @Stu my intention was to find a duplicate (ImageId) images and delete ALL of them, but not wipe the whole table data.

Comment: Write it as a `SELECT` first. When the `SELECT` produces the right records, then you are ready to turn it into a `DELETE`.

Comment: @HelloWorld your expected results, presumably after the delete, show the two duplicate ImageId `a` remaining and the other `b,c` rows deleted.

Comment: @Stu sh... fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery is not correlated, so it is simply deleting every row, as long as there is at least one row in the unrelated subquery.

The join is not necessary anyway, you just need to correlate it.

```sql
DELETE FROM Image 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM Image li
    WHERE li.ImageId = Image.ImageId
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

However this is probably more efficient with a window function

```sql
DELETE FROM li
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      Count = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY li.ImageId)
    FROM Image li
) li
WHERE li.Count > 1;
```

Note how the derived table is deleted from directly, no joins are necessary